# handling errors/data in asynchrounous networking calls

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                   queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
{

    NSDictionary * dictionary = nil;
    NSError * returnError = nil;
    NSString * errorCode = nil;
    NSString * errorText = nil;
    NSInteger newErrorCode = 0;

    if([data length] >= 1) {
        dictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: data options: 0 error: nil];
    }

    if(dictionary == nil) {

        newErrorCode = -1;
        errorText = @"There was an unexpected error.";
        NSMutableDictionary* details = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
        [details setValue: errorText forKey: NSLocalizedDescriptionKey];
        returnError = [NSError errorWithDomain: AppErrorDomain code: newErrorCode userInfo: details];

        responseHandler(nil, returnError);

        return;
    }

    NSInteger statusCode = [(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response statusCode];

    if(statusCode != 200)
    {
        if(dictionary != nil) {
            if([dictionary objectForKey: @"error_code"] != nil) {
                errorCode = [dictionary objectForKey: @"error_code"];
            }

            if([dictionary objectForKey: @"error_description"] != nil) {
                errorText = [dictionary objectForKey: @"error_description"];
            }
        }

        if(errorCode == nil)
        {
            newErrorCode = UnexpectedError;

            errorText =  NSLocalizedString(@"There was an unexpected error.", @"There was an unexpected error.");

        }
        else {
            newErrorCode = [errorCode intValue];
        }

        NSMutableDictionary* details = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
        [details setValue: errorText forKey: NSLocalizedDescriptionKey];
        returnError = [NSError errorWithDomain: APPErrorDomain code: newErrorCode userInfo: details];
    }

    responseHandler(dictionary, returnError);

    return;

}];
```

In my asynchronous networking call above, I check to see if the status code is not 200 and assume that is an error. Is that the correct way to handle error/data handling in networking calls in IOS?

Can we always assume that the NSError from the asynchronous request will always be non-nill if the http status code is not 200 and nill if it is 200?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the completionHandler's NSError will be non NULL if an error occurred. From there you can get the associated error code, domain, and description. If the NSError is not NULL you can then check which code it is a proceed from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand, if your `NSURLConnection` returns an error, than it means that no response from the server was received.

If the server sends its response, be it whatever HTTP code, `NSUrlConnection` will not give you any error (the error returned will be nil).

Indeed, `NSURLError.h` lists all errors related to NSURLConnection and they can be, e.g.:

```
NSURLErrorTimedOut
NSURLErrorCannotConnectToHost
NSURLErrorNetworkConnectionLost
NSURLErrorNotConnectedToInternet
```

so, this is the kind of errors that you can expect to find in the `NSError` object you receive back from your network call.

On the contrary, if you have an HTTP error, that means at least that the server could be reached, it replied, etc.

You can also see this in the context of networking layered architecture, whereby HTTP is an application protocol and HTTP errors only have meaning at that level.

On the other hand, `NSURLConnection` works at the transport level, below the application level. So an error at the application level has no meaning to it and is just "transported" transparently from one end to another.